# Probability and events

Tags: probability

Using only a coin,  a regular deck of playing cards and a 6 sided die, invent a game of chance where you have a 1 in 20 chance of winning in any given turn or attempt. You do not have to use all the items listed above, but you cannot use anything more.  you may use them multiple times and/or combine them in each attempt. For example, "a game is played by picking a card from the deck and tossing a coin twice." You win if you get 2 tails and a spade. Probability of winning is 1 /16. Describe your event, how you play and win the game, and show with calculations how the probability of winning = 1/20?

Comment: You might try to find 1/20 = 1/(something) times 1/(something else) times ... . How can you find something and something else (potentially multiple "something elses") so that the product is 20? Here's part of a solution. Tossing a coin and getting heads has probability 1/2. So 1/20 = 1/2 times 1/10. Can you figure out how to get probability of something = 1/10? Good luck and have fun.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about probability and mathematics instead of programming / coding / programming tools / software algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd get a better answer on mathematical site rather than a programming one. But here's my attempt:

It depends on what sort of rules you allow.

If you allow rules like: throw the dice; if its 1,2,3,4 you lose; if its 5 you win; if its a 6 repeat, then a game with a 1/20 chance of winning would be: throw a coin twice, if you don't get two heads you lose, if you do get two heads throw the dice as above.

If you don't allow such recursive rules then there is no such game. All the elementary events (throwing a particular side of the coin, picking a particular card, throwing a particular value of the dice) have probabilities that can be expressed as N/D where N and D are integers, and D can be factorised as a product of powers of 2,3 and 13. All events made by ands and ors and selections will have probabilities of this form, since they will be finite sums of finite products of probabilities of elementary events. But 1/20 isn't of this form, because 20 = 2*2*5